# Presto SQL: placeholder for "date" that must be greater than any other date

Tags: sql, presto

I have a query in Presto where I need to select some values based on date references of another table, structured like this:

```
ID    |   from     |    to
------+------------+-----------
A     |     -      |     
------+------------+-----------
B     | 2020-11-01 |     
------+------------+-----------
C     |     -      | 2020-12-31
```

What this table means is that item A is still valid, item B is valid only since 2020-11-01 and item C is valid only until 2020-12-31.

The query should work like this

```sql
SELECT whatever
  FROM table t
 WHERE any_date BETWEEN t.from AND t.to
```

Now, in Presto I've discovered that **any** date is greater than `-`. So if I do `SELECT '-' < '1930-01-01'`, it would return `true`.

This is good for me because there are some items that don't have an actual "From" value, so `-` is a good placeholder.

However, I haven't found a character / placeholder / wildcard / whatever that is **always** greater than any specific date.

Does something like this exist? If not, can you suggest a smart solution for this predicament, that doesn't require me adding fake dates like '2500-01-01' for those items that don't have a "to" field?

Comment: You should put in real values and not depend on such idiosyncrasies.  How about:   0001-01-01 and 9999-12-31.

Comment: Alright, so I guess the `-` < any_date is not intended. Of course, your solution would definitely work, I was just looking for something a bit more human readable.